# NSTimeInterval Always giving 0 interval

Tags: objective-c

I want to compare two dates and i m trying to do this by using `timeIntervalSinceDate` method with the below code :

```
NSTimeInterval timeinterval;
timeinterval = ([dateTo timeIntervalSinceDate:dateFrom]/86400); 
NSLog(@"--- intertval= %d", timeinterval);
```

But I am always getting 0 difference though the dates are different. I tried many ways But not getting any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
NSLog(@"--- intertval= %f", timeinterval);
```

Comment: Thats Really so silly mistake i spend almost 4 hrs for this. Thanqq Jhaliya.. A lot..

Answer (score 0):

NSTimeInterval is a double, not an int. Use the appropriate format specifier (`%f` or `%g`).